Is it possible to switch from dark mode to light mode in Twincat 3 HMI?
I have created a HMI for my project, and I used the Standard template version so that I do not have to code the backgrounds and I selected the dark mode for this. But now when I want to use light mode due to the Logo and other image related problems which cannot be changed. I am gone too far now and cannot restart the process.
Screenshot of the theme combobox
By default, in the Settings section, there is a option for changing the Theme but, everytime I restart the HMI or the PLC, the HMI will be in dark mode and a person has to mannually turn the base mode on. Does anyone know if it is even possible to change the theme permanently?

Select Project in your XAE Shell (or Visual Studio). Check properties window. Under deployment category you will find 'Theme Name' property. Set it to theme you want as default.
This should always start your client in selected theme.
You mentioned something similar in your question, if you are testing this in published server, you will need to publish again with new property.
